# Calculate leaves from table for more than 1 leave entry

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table in which *leave* will be updated.

It has the following columns:

```
id | empno | startdate | enddate | status | duration
```

Now I have to calculate the leave in a given month and year where the month and year will come from user input. I have a code which will retrieve the no. of leaves in the given month if the leave entry is 1.

The problem is that if the user has taken leave more than 1 time, the function is calculating only the last row from database. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?PHP
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "lms";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$empid    = (isset($_POST['empid'])    ? $_POST['empid']    : '');
$month = (isset($_POST['month'])    ? $_POST['month']    : '');

$month = "2015-sep"; 

$month1 = date('F', strtotime('$month'));
//echo $month1;

$year = date('Y',strtotime('$month'));

$monthStart = date("Y-m-1") . "<br/>";
$num = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, date("m"), date("Y"));
$monthEnd = date("Y-m-".$num)."<br/>";
//echo "$num";
$months = date('M');
$years = date ('Y');
$leave = 0;

if ($conn->connect_error)  {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT  `startdate`, `enddate`,`duration` FROM `leaves` WHERE `employee` = '2' AND `status` = '3' 
AND `startdate` > '01-09-2015' AND `enddate` < '30-09-2015' ";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
        $start = ($row['startdate']);
        $end =  ($row['enddate']);
        $startcount = ['COUNT(`employee`)'];
        //$durationlvs =  ($row['duration']);
           echo "sdate:$start,edate:$end</br>";  
          //echo "lvsdur:$durationlvs";
    }

    function getLeavesInPeriod($start, $end) {
        $date = new DateTime($start);
        $endDate = new DateTime($end);
        $leaves = array();

        while( $date <= $endDate ) {
            $year = $date->format('Y');
            $month = $date->format('M');        

            if(!array_key_exists($year, $leaves))
                $leaves[$year] = array();
            if(!array_key_exists($month, $leaves[$year]))
                $leaves[$year][$month] = 0;

            $leaves[$year][$month]++;           
            $date->modify("+1 day");
        }
    return $leaves;
}
$leaves = getLeavesInPeriod($start,$end);
$noofleaves=$leaves[$years][$months];
echo $noofleaves;
$conn->close();
}   
?>
```

Comment: can you supply a little more of your code if possible. I know you have shown a lot, but just a little more

Comment: @Drew Here's the code.....

Answer (score 1):

Just changed the SQL Query to

> $sql = "SELECT   SUM(DATEDIFF(LEAST(enddate, '2015-09-30'),
>   GREATEST(startdate, '2015-09-01'))+1) days 
>   FROM leaves WHERE
>   startdate<='2015-09-30' AND enddate>='2015-09-01' AND `employee`='2'
>   AND `status`='1'";

ufff!!! got the result.